# Enabling Additional CSS / custom-css

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Custom CSS is a feature since [4.7](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#Custom_CSS_in_WordPress)

> Just choose the Additional CSS tab when customizing your current theme to get started!

The problem is that a theme developed a while back does not show the *Additional CSS* tab.

I happened to be using twentythirteen as a base for another project, and there it is, nothing anywhere in the functions.php is enabling it, it just works.

**Anyone have any idea about how to enable it?**

While I can use the following:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_theme_css', array(
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'custom_theme_css', array(
  'label' => __( 'Custom Theme CSS' ),
  'type' => 'textarea',
  'section' => 'custom_css',
) );
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_css', array(
  'title' => __( 'Custom CSS' ),
  'description' => __( 'Add custom CSS here' ),
  'panel' => '', // Not typically needed.
  'priority' => 160,
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
  'theme_supports' => '', // Rarely needed.
) );
```

I am essentially creating a new setting, rather than using the new core feature.

I want to enable the core, something like `$wp_customize->add_section('custom_css');`

Comment: The custom css in 4.7 is enabled by default, it must be code in your theme or a plugin conflicting with the core code. Try disabling plugins and check if that helps, if not look inside your theme for `custom_css` customizer section as it might override core settings.

Comment: This is all that is removed:
` $wp_customize->remove_section('colors');
 $wp_customize->remove_section('header_image');
 $wp_customize->remove_section('background_image');
 $wp_customize->remove_section('static_front_page');
 $wp_customize->remove_control('blogdescription');
 $wp_customize->remove_control('display_header_text');
 $wp_customize->remove_control('site_icon'); `

Answer (score 1):

Lol, coming back to my own post 3 years later looking for answers.

Deactivating plugins did nothing, but ended up finding `WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control` which has options for `code_type`.

So here is a manual method for adding a proper CSS editor to a theme. This probably only useful for updating older themes that were already installed.

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_css', array(
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control( $wp_customize,'custom_css', array(
      'label' => __( 'Custom CSS' ),
      'code_type' => 'css',
      'section' => 'custom_css',
      'settings'  => 'custom_css',
    ) ));

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_css', array(
      'title' => __( 'Custom CSS' ),
      'description' => __( 'Add custom CSS here' ),
      'panel' => '', // Not typically needed.
      'priority' => 160,
      'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
      'theme_supports' => '', // Rarely needed.
    ) );

    $custom_css = get_theme_mod( 'custom_css', '' );
    wp_register_style( 'custom-css', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css' );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-css', $custom_css );

});
```